# resignFirstResponder of a UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I create the table cell like this (it's the first cell of the first section and the only cell with a textField in it):

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        GroupedTableViewCellWithTextField *cell = (GroupedTableViewCellWithTextField *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nameCellIdentifier];
        if (!cell && !_nameCell) {
            cell = [[GroupedTableViewCellWithTextField alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                                            reuseIdentifier: nameCellIdentifier];
            cell.textField.delegate = self;
            if (!_adding)
                cell.textField.text = @"Some Text";
            _nameCell = cell;
        }
        if (!cell) {
            cell = _nameCell;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

The textField is created by a simple

```
- (UITextField *)textField {
    if (!_textField) {
        CGRect rect = self.bounds;
        CGFloat cellWidth = rect.size.width;
        CGFloat cellHeight = rect.size.height;
        CGRect cellRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 15, rect.origin.y, cellWidth - 48, cellHeight);

        _textField = [[SSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: cellRect];
        _textField.textColor = self.textLabel.textColor;
        _textField.placeholderTextColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        _textField.placeholder = @"Name";
        _textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        _textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        _textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        _textField.alpha = 1.0f;
        [_textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_textField];
    }
    return _textField;
}
```

Then I have:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([_nameCell.textField isFirstResponder]) {
        [_nameCell.textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

And the problem is as follows: If I scroll down, until the cell with the textField is out of screen and I resignFirstResponder, I get

```
no index path for table cell being reused
```

BUT only once. If I touch inside the cell with the textField, its textField gets firstResponder again, then scroll down again and resignFirstResponder, I don't get that error again ... It only displays the first time.

if I

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]
                atScrollPosition: UITableViewRowAnimationTop
                    animated: YES];
```

the scroll is too slow and I still get the error. If I do it non animated, I don't get the error anymore, since the cell gets displayed faster than resignFirstResponder is called; but it looks and feels ugly.

I also tried to resignFirstResponder on

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

so it happens before the cell leaves the view, but the animation is choppy: the scroll begins, then stops for a split second while the keyboard starts moving down, then starts again.

Just to make myself clear, the resignFirstResponder works.

I should note that the table is big enough to need scrolling while keyboard is displayed, but small enough to fit on screen when keyboard is not displayed.

Also, if the table is scrolled down until the cell is not on screen anymore, the error also appears if I pop the view.

I would like to keep the table scrollable, I know I can turn that off.

Any ideas on how to stop the error from appearing, but without making the app feel choppy or non animated? Everything else works properly: data saving, data displaying, responders, I get no crashes, etc.

I know it's not a critical error and I can let it be, but still, I'd like to have no errors :)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found the solution

Comment: Have you use UItapgesture

Comment: Either iOS 7 improved something, either I found a workaround, but honestly, I can't remember what it was, if so. Sorry :(

Comment: i did that by retrieve textfield from cell and then resign its responder